# How to add values to hidden div fields using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a situation like there will be one hidden div

```
<div id="div_id">
     <input type="text" id="input_id" name="input_name">
</div
```

I have hidden the div using hide() function using jquery

```
  $('#div_id').hide();
```

Now my problem is how can I add values to above input field and display the values when I show the div.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("select#po_pos").change(function()
       {
           var stateId = $("#po_pos option:selected").val();
           $('#input_id').val($('#').val() + stateId);
       }
 });
```

can anyone help on this please??thanks

Comment: on div show you can get value form that input and show in label using jquery

Comment: Can you please explain what's this code '$('#input_id').val($('#').val() + stateId);'.

Comment: @vikalp I am trying to append state id to the input box

Answer (score 1):

You were missing the input box id. This may help you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#po_pos").change(function()
       {
           var stateId = $("#po_pos option:selected").val();
           $('#input_id').val($('#input_id').val() + stateId);
       });
       $("#btn1").click(function()
       {
           $('#div_id').show();
       });
       $("#btn2").click(function()
       {
           $('#div_id').hide();
       });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_id">
     <input type="text" id="input_id" name="input_name">
</div>
<select id="po_pos">
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Show"/>
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Hide"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this :

```
<div id="div_id">
     <input type="text" id="input_id" name="input_name">
</div>

<script>        
  $('#div_id').hide();

   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("select#po_pos").change(function()
       {
           var stateId = $("#po_pos option:selected").val();
           var inputVal = $('#'+stateId).val();
           $('#input_id').val(inputVal);
           $('#div_id').show();
       }
 });
</script>
```